# Find the PDF of $1-X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Given 2 jars(A,B) with 1 liter in each of them first we move from A to B random amount X(uniform) and then return Y (uniform).

Find the PDF of $1-X+Y$ after two transfers
$\mathbb{P}(1-X+Y\leq t)=\int_0^1\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x-(1-t))dx=\int_0^1F_{\mbox{U(0,1+x)}}(x-(t-1))dx$
for $0<t<1$ I found that $\int_{1-t}^1F_{\mbox{U(0,1+x)}}(x-(t-1))dx $

and for $1<t<2$ I don't know how to determine the boundaries of the integral, any help would be good :)

Comment: Looks like you've done the harder part -- if $1<t<2$, then $x$ can be anything in $[0,1]$, so your integral in that case should run from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: This question is from an exam and apparently if  $1<t<2 $ we have 2 parts to look at from 0 to 2-t and from 2-t to 1 but I don't get why these are boundaries